# How can add  I rownumbers for each group on a RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reportviewer, rdlc

How can ı add row numbers like this:

**GROUP 1**

RowNumber     ID      Name     Age

```
1            231     test     43
2            324     test2    45
3            354     test3    34
```

**GROUP 2**

RowNumber     ID      Name     Age

```
1          657     test4    43
2          534     test5    45
3          678     test6    34
```

I want to do row numbers like this example.. For each group my row numbers will reset and start from 1 to groups row count..  My gruops(GROUP 1,GROUP 2, ....) are coming from db dynamically! How many group I have is not clear! [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/152050/How-can-I-add-a-row-number-at-each-grouping-header) is I found some solutions but I think those solutions are available for how many groups when we know!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RDLCs have a `RowNumber("ScopeName")` Function.  This will return the row number of the record within the given scope.

You can see the existing groups for the report below the designer under a "Row Groups" and "Column Groups" headers.  Select the column inside the grouping where you want the row number and view the Row Columns,  The default names will be:

```
[(Group1)
 ≡(Details1)
```

Set the expression for the Row Number column to be

```
=RowNumber("Group1")
```

Comment: Still, your solution saves our day!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on your Report property then go to **code** then paste the code below

```
   Dim private count as integer = 0
   Dim private iniRow as integer = 0
   Dim private iniGrp as Object = ""
   Public function MatrixRow(Byval rowNum as integer,Byval rowGrp as Object) as integer

   if iniGrp = "" then
      iniGrp = rowGrp 
   end if

  if rowGrp <> iniGrp then
      iniRow = 0 
      count = 0 
      iniGrp = rowGrp 
  end if

  if iniRow = 0 then
      iniRow = rowNum
  end if

  if rowNum = iniRow then
     count = 0
  end if

   count = count + 1
   Return count
  End function
```

then use this function like

```
   =Code.MatrixRow(RowNumber(Nothing),(YourgroupfiledNameFromDataest))
```

Comment: This is working except every page the counter resets so it displays 1, 2 .. so on again.

Comment: This put me on the right track, but I really wanted my table rows to be numbered regardless of data or groups or anything else, so I just removed the references to `iniGrp`, `rowGrp` and the two `if..then`. statements including them from the code, and the second parameter in the function call and it worked perfectly.