# How to create serial number for each group in rdlc?

Tags: grouping, reportviewer, rdlc, row-number

i have create a report with serial number using rownumber(nothing) in rdcl report. since, i have used a group in the report, the serial number is continued with the previous group
I get the report like

Group1    1     value 
             2  value

             3     value

Group2    4     value 
             5  value

             6     value

But i need it like

Group1    1     value 
             2  value

             3     value

Group2    1     value 
             2  value

             3     value

I even tried with RunningValue function. Is it possible the way i need it?

Comment: Check this out [how-can-add-i-rownumbers-for-each-group-on-a-rdlc-report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770743/how-can-add-i-rownumbers-for-each-group-on-a-rdlc-report)

Answer (score 5):

For creating serial number for each group in rdlc you can use following syntax

**=RowNumber("table1_Group1")** as expression in the text field

where table1_Group1 is group name .